# How do I configure ESLint to allow fat arrow class methods

Tags: javascript, eslint, class-fields

ESLint is throwing a `Parsing error: Unexpected token =` error when I try to lint my Es6 classes.  What configuration parameter am I missing to enable fat arrow class methods in eslint?

Sample class:

```
class App extends React.Component{
    ...
    handleClick = (evt) => {
        ...
    }
}
```

.eslint

```
{
  "ecmaFeatures": {
    "jsx": true,
    "modules":true,
    "arrowFunctions":true,
    "classes":true,
    "spread":true,

  },
  "env": {
    "browser": true,
    "node": true,
    "es6": true
  },
  "rules": {
    "strict": 0,
    "no-underscore-dangle": 0,
    "quotes": [
      2,
      "single"
    ],
  }
}
```

Comment: The `arrowFunctions` you already include should cover it. This may be an unsupported case, a bug or against the convention style

Comment: Is it ESLint that throws the error or the transpiler?

Comment: Have you tried using babel-eslint?

Comment: That's not an ES6 class. That's an experimental ES7 proposal.

Comment: Yup, it's an es7 proposal (which, IMO, is an obvious contender for inclusion).  

I solved this by using `babel-eslint` as my linter.  It's a drop in replacement for eslint with a babel parser stuck on the end.  

Thanks to all of you who chimed in.

Answer (score 51, accepted):

If you want to use experimental features (such as arrows as class methods) you need to use [`babel-eslint`](https://github.com/babel/babel-eslint) as a parser. Default parser (Espree) doesn't support experimental features.

Comment: Some more details here https://medium.com/@chestozo/fixing-eslint-no-invalid-this-error-for-fat-arrow-class-methods-a56908ca8bb6

Comment: make sure you use babel-eslint >= 10.0.0

Answer (score 34):

First install `babel-eslint`:

```
npm i -D babel-eslint
```

Then add the following to your `.eslintrc.json` file:

```
"parser": "babel-eslint"
```

Comment: I used this solution.  
Only, before installing I ran
    npm -g ls | grep babel | grep eslint
and found that I already had the module installed globally, so I only did the .eslintrc thing.

Comment: Worked like a charm for me!

Answer (score 9):

First install these plugins:

```
npm i -D babel-eslint eslint-plugin-babel
```

Then add these settings to your ESLint config file:

```
{
    "plugins": [ "babel" ],
    "parser": "babel-eslint",
    "rules": {
        "no-invalid-this": 0,
        "babel/no-invalid-this": 1,
    }
}
```

This way you can use fat arrow class methods plus you will not get any `no-invalid-this` errors from ESLint.

Comment: how do I add this to the eslint file ?

Answer (score 8):

From what I read in the error message `Parsing error: Unexpected token =` it looks like more a parser error than linter one.

Assuming you are using [Babel](http://babeljs.io/) as your JavaScript compiler/transpiler and [`babel-eslint`](https://github.com/babel/babel-eslint) as your ESLint parser, chances are that it is Babel complaining about the syntax, not ESLint.

The issue is not about the arrow functions but something more experimental (ES7??) that I think it is called [property initializer](https://facebook.github.io/react/blog/2015/01/27/react-v0.13.0-beta-1.html#autobinding) or [class instance field](https://github.com/jeffmo/es-class-fields-and-static-properties) (or both :) ).

If you want to use this new syntax/feature you need to enable [`preset-stage-1`](http://babeljs.io/docs/plugins/preset-stage-1/) in Babel. This preset includes the [`syntax-class-properties`](http://babeljs.io/docs/plugins/syntax-class-properties/) plugin that allows that syntax.

Summing up:

1. Install babel preset:

   ```
   npm install babel-preset-stage-1
   ```
2. Add this preset to the list of your presets (I suppose you are already using `es2015` and `react` presets), either in your `.babelrc` or in your [`babel-loader`](https://github.com/babel/babel-loader) query field if you are using webpack.

   ```
   "presets": ["es2015", "stage-1", "react"]
   ```

Answer (score 5):

I came across the same problem today

and @dreyescat 's answer works for me.

By default, babel uses 3 presets: `es2015`, `react`, `stage-2`

[Screenshot with "Parsing error: Unexpected token ="](https://i.stack.imgur.com/mmtRT.png)

Then if you also select the `stage-1`preset, the error is gone

[Screenshot with no error](https://i.stack.imgur.com/0NR30.png)

You can test it on the bebeljs.io site yourself

Answer (score 3):

#### 2021 Update: Be sure you're using `@babel/eslint-parser` and not the deprecated `babel-eslint`

1. Remove the old package if necessary: `yarn remove babel-eslint` or `npm uninstall babel-eslint`
2. `yarn add --dev @babel/eslint-parser` or `npm install --save-dev @babel/eslint-parser`
3. In `.eslintrc` add `"parser": "@babel/eslint-parser"`

Optionally, [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/69557309/1038034) suggests including `"requireConfigFile": false` in `.eslintrc` to prevent eslint from searching for unnecessary config files:

```
{
  ...
  "parserOptions": {
    ...
    "requireConfigFile": false,
  }
}
```

#### If this still doesn't work, try checking whether your system is using a globally installed eslint (and removing it).

My other problem was eslint was using a globally installed version instead of my local version, and the global eslint [can't access my locally installed babel-eslint parser](https://github.com/microsoft/vscode-eslint/issues/13#issuecomment-177991758). Further, since my globally installed eslint was installed on a different version of node, removing it was non-trivial.

##### Checking if your system is using global versus local eslint.

1. Install `babel-eslint` [following @spencer.sm's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/52806720/1038034) for your local eslint.
2. From the terminal, check if you get different output from running `eslint .` and `npx eslint .`. If you get different output it's likely that it's your global eslint running that can't access babel-eslint.

##### Uninstalling the global eslint

For most people, the following commands should uninstall eslint with npm ([uninstall global package with npm](https://stackoverflow.com/a/44962536/1038034)) and yarn ([uninstall global package with yarn](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/66401964/how-to-uninstall-a-globally-installed-package-with-yarn)):

```sh
# npm
npm uninstall -g eslint
npm uninstall eslint

# yarn
yarn global remove eslint
```

Next, run `npx eslint .` to see if things work. If it doesn't, which it didn't for me, you need to take an extra step to remove the globally installed eslint.

From [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/47849940/1038034), I learned that I had installed eslint on a system version of Node instead of my current version of Node (I use nvm). Follow [these simple steps](https://stackoverflow.com/a/47849940/1038034) to remove the global eslint and you should be good to go!

Answer (score -6):

Your sample isn't valid ES6, so there's no way to configure eslint to allow it

Comment: Check out [Arrow functions](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Functions/Arrow_functions)