# ESLint in class with fat arrow using airbnb rules

Tags: reactjs, babeljs, lint, eslint

The following code located in a class that extends `React.Component`

```
  nextState = () => {
    this.setState({
      state : this.state.state + 1
    });
  };
```

However ESLint with airbnb rules catches this and throws the following error:
`error  Parsing error: Unexpected token =`

I would like to keep this syntax as it allows me to avoid binding `this` in the constructor.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How do I configure ESLint to allow fat arrow class methods](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/34244888/how-do-i-configure-eslint-to-allow-fat-arrow-class-methods)

Answer (score 11, accepted):

I struggled with this problem for quite a while.
I found that this configuration of `.eslintrc` works for your problem.

```
{
  "extends": "airbnb",
  "parser": "babel-eslint"
}
```

It works nicely with Sublime Text 3 with SublimeLinter-contrib-eslint.

Note that you need to `npm install -g eslint babel-eslint`

put `.eslintrc` in `~/` for global config, put `.eslintrc` in app folder to overwrite global config.

**also note that:** Assignment operation inside class is not part of es6, see this [link](https://github.com/babel/babelify/pull/172) for discussion

Answer (score 4):

You need to specify Language options. For ref: http://eslint.org/docs/user-guide/configuring#specifying-language-options

You can do this with a single command also inside your `.eslintrc` file.

```
{
    "env": {
        "es6": true,
        "node": true
    }
}
```