# How to uninstall global package with npm?

Tags: node.js, npm, webpack

I have installed webpack in this way:

```
npm install -g webpack
```

Now want to uninstall it:

```
npm uninstall -g webpack
```

Check it again, it didn't been uninstalled:

```
webpack -v
3.1.0
```

Why?

---

And, I use this way can't find `webpack`:

```
npm list -g | grep webpack
```

---

This also didn't work:

```
npm uninstall -g webpack --save
```

---

After run this under a directory which included `package.json`:

```
npm uninstall webpack
npm WARN babel-loader@6.4.1 requires a peer of webpack@1 || 2 || ^2.1.0-beta || ^2.2.0-rc but none was installed.
npm WARN uglifyjs-webpack-plugin@0.3.1 requires a peer of uglify-js@^2.8.0 but none was installed.
npm WARN uglifyjs-webpack-plugin@0.3.1 requires a peer of webpack@^1.9 || ^2 || ^2.1.0-beta || ^2.2.0-rc but none was installed.
```

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13066532/how-to-uninstall-npm-modules-in-node-js

Comment: @Sujith `npm uninstall -g webpack --save` also didn't work.

Comment: Do you have a webpack local version installed along with global? Try running "npm uninstall webpack" . I think you might have deleted it the global version and trying to check the local webpack version

Comment: Often when people install globally they use `sudo`. If so, you'd have to use `sudo npm uninstall -g webpack`, too.

Comment: npm might be preventing you of uninstalling this module since it is needed by some other else

Comment: You ever get this solved?

Comment: Check also where your node executable resides; there might be a script, with node_modules folder in case npm config/installation got messed up, which gets executed.

Answer (score 97):

Try running both of the below commands:

```
npm uninstall -g webpack
npm uninstall webpack
```

I think you might be checking/looking at the local version after deleting only the global one.

Comment: I did that. Then got new errors. Put them to the bellow of question.

Comment: I had to remove manually the folder and the symlink, `npm uninstall -g` would not do it for some reason. `whereis <package>` can help locate the folder.

Answer (score 25):

You have to remove the packages manually installed globally on your os with sudo:

On OsX navigate to this directory

```
cd /usr/local/lib/node_modules
```

and

```
sudo rm -rf <packageName> // sudo rm -rf webpack
```

Comment: More generally, run `which <packageName>`. Then run `rm -rf` on the directory/file that makes sense (maybe there's a root directory or you get an alias file which references the main binary, which you may notice when running `ls -l $(which <packageNameAlias>)`, in which case, you might want to delete both the original binary file and the alias). YMMV.

Comment: I also had to manually delete it like this on Ubuntu.

Comment: Confirming this works. Looks like after installing `nvm`, the program didn't move all my global scripts from local to `.nvm` folders where specific node versions live

Answer (score 12):

```
npm uninstall -g webpack
```

Worked for me, try running the command prompt in administrator mode.

Answer (score 11):

I have tried uninstalling global packages in several ways.

`npm uninstall -g <package_name>` this didn't work.

I managed to remove the global packages in the following way:

- Goto terminal
- Run this command `npm list -g`
- Goto the path (`C:\Users\user\AppData\Roaming\npm`)
- Delete all the related files to your package
- Goto `node_modules` find and delete the package

This should work.

YW!

Comment: THE BEST OPTION! npm has gone haywire with versions. It's version hell now days.

Answer (score 9):

You're most likely running a file from another install of npm.

Run `which webpack` to see where your shell is finding webpack.

Run `npm root -g` to find the root of the tree it's supposed to be in, being sure you're running the correct npm with `npm -v` and `which npm`.

If your webpack bin isn't in the npm root, reset your path to the webpack binary e.g. `hash -d webpack` in bash, and then go remove the unwanted npm root from your PATH variable. You can now use `npm install -g webpack` and `npm uninstall -g webpack` and it should work.

Answer (score 6):

If you are using Node Version Manager (nvm) and you want to remove a global system package you will need to switch to that version. For example:

```sh
nvm use system
npm uninstall -g webpack
```

Comment: Thanks for the shortcut to change back to the system version - I always ended up looking in my distro to see the current system version number!

Answer (score 2):

Try

```
chown -R "$(whoami)": "$(npm root -g)"
```

(you may need sudo for it) and then npm uninstall -g  again

Comment: I even as a root user now. I have tried your way, but the same result. The `3.1.0` of webpack also exists.

Answer (score 1):

on windows run as administrator and run the command

```
npm uninstall -g webpack
```

on Linux

```
sudo npm uninstall -g webpack
```

Answer (score 1):

In Windows, open the cmd with Administrator rights (start -> type cmd -> right-click on icon -> open with adm. rights), then navigate (in cmd type "cd ../../users/your_user_name") to your user folder, then run

```
npm uninstall -g webpack
```

or (I don't remember which one worked for me)

```
npm uninstall webpack
```

Answer (score 0):

Had the same issue an none of the answer above helped.

My project was in a sub-directory of a larger project, which also had a node_modules folder.

That's why it says, something like "found another version higher in the tree."

Delete that folder, go back to your sub-dir, remove node_modules and package-lock.json, and finally run npm install again.

Answer (score 0):

In archlinux, after running

> `npm uninstall -g <package_name>`

you might have to manually enter /usr/lib/node_modules/ to remove the package's directory. This will prevent conflicts if you try reinstalling that package with a different package manager like pacman.

Answer (score 0):

Building on  [@karthik006 's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/61669532/11565176) of deleting directly from the global `node_module` folder, if you are using nvm, you first need to decide from which version of node you want to delete the global package.

After that, switch to that version of node using `nvm use <version>`

Then run `nvm which current` to get the path where the executable for this version of node is saved.
The path will be something like `<path to nvm node dir>/<node version>/bin/node`

Using this path, cd into `<path to nvm node dir>/<node version>/lib/node_modules` and then `rm -rf` the packages that you want to remove.

Answer (score 0):

On ubuntu the package I was on the hunt for was buried in `~/.npm/_npx/<chars>/node_modules/` and in `~/.npm/_npx/<chars>/node_modules/.bin/`. I removed the bin and the directory and got the reinstall prompt.

Answer (score 0):

For Linux users, after `npm uninstall -g <package_name>`, check in your home directory if there is any folder with this package name.

Using the `locate` and `find` commands, I have noticed that some globally installed  packages create extra folders in home directory. Remove them as well `rm -rf ~/.<package_name>/`

Answer (score -1):

Try This:

```
npm uninstall -g <package_name> 
E.g: npm uninstall -g webpack
```