# How to globally uninstall an npm package commitizen?

Tags: node.js, npm, commitizen

I'm trying to [uninstall a globally installed NPM package](https://stackoverflow.com/a/44962536/2404470) named [commitizen](https://www.npmjs.com/package/commitizen).

I have tried executing the command below, however; the command fails to return any results.

```
  npm uninstall -g commitizen
```

[image: up to date in 0.035s]

I restarted the machine.

To check whether or not the package was removed I tried running `commitizen`. I expected an error, as it should have been removed. To my surprise the package executed.

[image: commitizen]

The result of `npm list -g --depth 0 or npm list -g commitizen`:

[image: npm list -g --depth 0 or npm list -g commitizen]

The result of `npm list -g commitizen`:

[image: npm list -g commitizen]

The result of `cd /usr/local/lin/node_modules`

[image: cd /usr/local/lin/node_modules]

So the question is what is the right approach of globally deleting the npm package?

Answer (score 1):

One way to check would be running `npm list -g --depth 0 or npm list -g commitizen`

If you want to check the package locally, head to `/usr/local/lin/node_modules`

Answer (score 1):

[Uninstalling global packages](https://docs.npmjs.com/uninstalling-packages-and-dependencies#uninstalling-global-packages) might answer this question:

> "So the question is what is the right approach of globally deleting the npm package?"

In addition, I had a similar problem on windows 10. I solve it just by upgrading [npm to the latest version](https://docs.npmjs.com/try-the-latest-stable-version-of-npm#upgrading-on-nix-osx-linux-etc).

Make sure it works with `npm ls -g --depth=0` or `npm list -g commitizen`.

If that still doesn't work try to running `npm uninstall -g commitizen` one more time.