# How to install Gulp.js v4 globally with Yarn?

Tags: node.js, gulp, yarnpkg

I installed Gulp.js globally with Yarn:

```
$ yarn global add gulp --no-bin-links
yarn global v1.17.3
[1/4] Resolving packages...
warning gulp > glob-watcher > anymatch > micromatch > snapdragon > source-map-resolve > urix@0.1.0: Please see https://github.com/lydell/urix#deprecated
warning gulp > glob-watcher > anymatch > micromatch > snapdragon > source-map-resolve > resolve-url@0.2.1: https://github.com/lydell/resolve-url#deprecated
[2/4] Fetching packages...
info fsevents@1.2.12: The platform "linux" is incompatible with this module.
info "fsevents@1.2.12" is an optional dependency and failed compatibility check. Excluding it from installation.
[3/4] Linking dependencies...
[4/4] Building fresh packages...

success Installed "gulp@4.0.2" with binaries:
      - gulp
Done in 5.76s.
```

```
$ yarn global add gulp-cli --no-bin-links
yarn global v1.17.3
[1/4] Resolving packages...
[2/4] Fetching packages...
info fsevents@1.2.12: The platform "linux" is incompatible with this module.
info "fsevents@1.2.12" is an optional dependency and failed compatibility check. Excluding it from installation.
[3/4] Linking dependencies...
[4/4] Building fresh packages...

success Installed "gulp-cli@2.2.0" with binaries:
      - gulp
Done in 1.60s.
```

<sub>(I'm using the `--no-bin-links` parameter to avoid this error: `error An unexpected error occurred: "EPROTO: protocol error, symlink '../../../semver/bin/semver' -> '/path/to/project/public/components/accord/node_modules/.bin/semver'"`.)</sub>

The `yarn global list` provides the expected output:

```
$ yarn global list
yarn global v1.17.3
info "gulp@4.0.2" has binaries:
   - gulp
info "gulp-cli@2.2.0" has binaries:
   - gulp
Done in 0.53s.
```

But when I now execute `gulp`, old versions (Gulp `3.9.1` and Gulp CLI `2.2.0` are used:

```
$ gulp -v
CLI version: 2.2.0
Local version: 3.9.1
```

**What is wrong here and how to install the required Gulp version globally correctly with Yarn *and* make this version be used?**

Comment: Have you tried uninstalling gulp using npm (which I assume you used to install 3.9.1)? https://stackoverflow.com/a/44962536/3650835

Comment: Thanks for your comment! Yes, before Yarn I used Gulp as npm package. Yes, tried to remove it, but ist not there anymore: `$ npm uninstall -g gulp` `->` `up to date in 0.04s`. (The same for Gulp CLI) And the package is actually not there anymore: `npm list -g | grep "gulp"` `->` `gulp-sourcemaps@1.6.0, gulp-choose-files@0.1.3`.

Comment: Hmm, I would remove all gulp artifacts (the v4 you added, cli, etc). Restart your computer. Doing `gulp -v` should then show gulp is not installed. Also note though that gulp can be installed locally in a project, so make sure you're in say a top level folder of your machine, not in a project that may have had gulp installed