# how to remove webpack 4.44

Tags: webpack, webpack-4

I'd like to uninstall webpack 4.44.1. The SO post [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/55798652/3549766) on this did not work for me.  When I run:

```
> npm uninstall -g webpack@4.44.1
up to date in 0.134s
```

and then when I run:

```
npm list -g webpack@4.44.1
```

it shows:

```
C:\Users\me\AppData\Roaming\npm
`-- (empty)
```

But, when I run:

```
npm ls
```

It gives me:

```
+-- moment@2.27.0
+-- webpack@4.44.1
| +-- @webassemblyjs/ast@1.9.0
| | +-- @webassemblyjs/helper-module-context@1.9.0 deduped
| | +-- @webassemblyjs/helper-wasm-bytecode@1.9.0
| | `-- @webassemblyjs/wast-parser@1.9.0
| |   +-- @webassemblyjs/ast@1.9.0 deduped
| |   +-- @webassemblyjs/floating-point-hex-parser@1.9.0
| |   +-- @webassemblyjs/helper-api-error@1.9.0 deduped
| |   +-- @webassemblyjs/helper-code-frame@1.9.0
| |   | `-- @webassemblyjs/wast-printer@1.9.0 deduped
| |   +-- @webassemblyjs/helper-fsm@1.9.0
| |   ... (for brevity, I am not including the rest)
```

So, my question is why is the webpack 4.44.1 shows up again and how to effectively uninstall it?

Answer (score 1):

Try running
npm uninstall -g webpack --save
npm uninstall webpack --save

Run the two lines of code above

Comment: It kind of worked.  The webpack was uninstalled, but npm complains that ```npm ERR! peer dep missing: webpack@4.x.x, required by webpack-cli@3.3.12```  So, how do I uninstall webpack-cli?

Answer (score 0):

ok install this npm module
npm i -D webpack-cli @webpack-cli/remove
go to the current project you are having problems with
and run this command

const remove = require("@webpack-cli/remove").default;

remove();

or via terminal

npx webpack-cli remove

try that and see how it goes