# trying to create a new react project by (create-react-app) it is not working properly

Tags: reactjs, create-react-app

I installed latest version of node.js, react.js and next.js
Everything worked properly but at the point I try to create my react project folder in the terminal by **`create-react-app my-app`** it tells me this:

**You are running `create-react-app` 5.0.0, which is behind the latest release (5.0.1).
We no longer support global installation of Create React App.**

the problem began while I was already working on a project but one day when I did **`npm start`**
I got an error I couldn't solve so I decided to create a new project and then that happened did any one got this lately ?

Comment: If you installed `create-react-app` globally, remove it with `npm uninstall -g create-react-app`. Then you can run `npx create-react-app`.

Comment: I already did this and it didn't uninstall the create-react-app module globally and i tried these commands  
`npm uninstall -g create-react-app`
`npx clear-npx-cache`
`npx create-react-app@latest my-app`
and i tried to force the latest version
it didn't do anything

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Uninstall create-react-app and run npx create-react-app@latest instead. Then you'll use the latest version of create-react-app

Comment: I already did this and it didn't uninstall the create-react-app module globally and i tried these commands `npm uninstall -g create-react-app` `npx clear-npx-cache` `npx create-react-app@latest my-app` and i tried to force the latest version it didn't do anything

Comment: Just in case, try npm uninstall create-react-app (not -g), in case there is a local install too. It's just a long shot, but could be worth a try?

There might be some good suggestions here though: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44962349/how-to-uninstall-global-package-with-npm?msclkid=853d08acc02e11ec828e676ca5e56839

Comment: what a long shot man, it did work when i ran **`npm uninstall create-react-app`** and then run **`npx create-react-app my-app`** the react project created successfully 
thank you so much for the information really appreciate it

Answer (score 2):

Try to remove current version that you have locally and do it with latest version

```
npm uninstall -g create-react-app
npx clear-npx-cache
npx create-react-app@latest my-app
```

Comment: it worked but if when I ran the **`npm uninstall create-react-app`**
because there was local installation the (-g) doesn't remove the local
,thank you tho