# ESLint shows error on class instance property initialized to arrow function

Tags: javascript, ecmascript-6, babeljs, eslint, class-fields

maybe similar to [How do I configure ESLint to allow fat arrow class methods](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34244888/how-do-i-configure-eslint-to-allow-fat-arrow-class-methods)

When class method defined as arrow function Eslint highlight error 'method' is not defined. (no-undef).
simple example

```
class abc {
  d = () => {
    // method body
  }
}
```

here is not difined 'd'

[image: class method is not defined]

my .eslintrc config

```
{
    "env": {
        "browser": true,
        "es6": true
    },
    "extends": [
      "eslint:recommended",
      "plugin:flowtype/recommended"
    ],
    "parser": "babel-eslint",
    "parserOptions": {
        "ecmaFeatures": {
            "experimentalObjectRestSpread": true,
            "jsx": true
        },
        "sourceType": "module"
    },
    "plugins": [
        "react",
        "flowtype"
    ],
    "rules": {
        "indent": [
            "error",
            2
        ],
        "linebreak-style": [
            "error",
            "unix"
        ],
        "quotes": [
            "error",
            "single"
        ],
        "semi": [
            "error",
            "always"
        ]
    }
}
```

.babelrc

```
{
  "presets": ["react", "es2015", "stage-1", "flow"]
}
```

Maybe I need to declare some rules?

Comment: ES6 classes do not have instance variables, which is what `d` is here.

Comment: arrow functions don't make sense in a `class` - just like setting `Something.prototype.somefunction = () => {}` makes no sense

Comment: @torazaburo - the `class` syntax doesn't provide for instance variables, but the resulting classes can have them if created in methods. (Just being picking about wording.) (So my wording is probably wrong too.)

Comment: Do you get the error if you run ESLint in the CLI? Sounds more like your editor just doesn't pick up the `.eslintrc`.

Comment: In `.eslintrc` add `"ecmaVersion": 7,` under `parserOptions`.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

as mentioned by [MinusFour answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45726238/eslint-shows-error-on-class-instance-property-initialized-to-arrow-function/45726856#comment78410639_45726375), I'm try to run eslint by command line, and I don't see that error.

My editor was configured wrong. (path to node_modules folder in linter-eslint package for atom was wrong). After I delete this path and restart editor everything is ok.

Comment: was running into same thing with VSCode, was using ESLint plugin, reinstalled the plugin and now the linter in the editor behaves in pair with what I see in the terminal.

Answer (score 0):

[This is something that hasn't made its way into Javascript yet](https://babeljs.io/docs/plugins/transform-class-properties/). It's available as an experimental plugin with babel, so you'll need to change the default parser for eslint with [`babel-eslint`](https://www.npmjs.com/package/babel-eslint).

Comment: yes, you're right. And in .eslint config file I set parser to babel-eslint (you can see it on question). But it didn't help.

Comment: @n06rin, I just noticed that. It works fine for me though, which version of eslint and babel-eslint are you using?

Comment: I'm using eslint@4.4.1 and babel-eslint@7.2.3

Comment: @n06rin, i have the same packages then. Try running it directly from the command line and not from your editor.

Comment: interesting, when I'm run eslint from command line, that didn't show that error. I assume something wrong with my editor. Thanks.

Comment: @n06rin, it must be running a global version of `eslint` that is outdated, try updating both (eslint and babel-eslint) globally.