# ESLint Parsing error: Unexpected token on equals sign after onSubmit function

Tags: reactjs, eslint

I'm having trouble getting rid of an error on my the equals sign =.
I'm using eslint recommended settings and tried using the experimentalobjectrestspread to rectify the issue from another answer on here.

The error still persists.

Here is my eslint file.

```
{
"extends": "eslint:recommended",
"parserOptions": {
    "sourceType": "module",
    "ecmaVersion": 6,
    "ecmaFeatures": {
        "jsx": true,
        "experimentalObjectRestSpread": true
    }
},
"env": {
    "node": true,
    "browser": true,
    "es6": true
},
"rules": {
    "no-console": "off",
    "no-unused-vars": "off"
}
```

}

Code with error **(only on the first equals after onSubmit)**

```
export class AddExp extends React.Component {
    onSubmit = (expense) => {
        this.props.addExpense(expense);
        this.props.history.push('/');
    };
```

Comment: You're using a class property, this is not something that is yet in the language.

Comment: Hi @Axnyff how so? How do I rectify this issue, change the code? change the eslint file?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How do I configure ESLint to allow fat arrow class methods](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34244888/how-do-i-configure-eslint-to-allow-fat-arrow-class-methods)

Comment: babel-eslint might help you to use that features

Comment: @digit I'm install npm babel-eslint and I'll see if it takes away the issue and also babel-preset-stage-1 from Axnyff link

Comment: Now I'm getting another error - [eslint] 'props' is not defined. But the = error is gone

Comment: I'm now using airbnb eslint rules