# How to uninstall a globally installed package with Yarn?

Tags: yarnpkg, quasar

I installed Quasar framework using Yarn:

`yarn global add @quasar/cli`

However there seems to be an issue with the installation and I now need to remove the global package. I checked the Yarn docs and they have a remove command but it does not seem to be global. I know NPM allow for global remove with:

`npm uninstall -g @quasar/cli`

How can I do the same with Yarn?

Answer (score 46):

you have to read yarn documentation

```
yarn global remove @quasar/cli
```

https://classic.yarnpkg.com/en/docs/cli/global

Comment: If you installed a global package with sudo, it might have been installed to /usr/local/bin instead. (You can check with `which <command>`.) In that case, you will have to use sudo to uninstall it as well.

Answer (score 1):

In Linux:

```
which <the package name: packageXYZ>
```

output: /home/user1234/.nvm/versions/node/v16.13.0/bin/packageXYZ

go there and delete it!

Answer (score 0):

I tried to delete with `yarn global remove <package_name>` but in my **MacOS**, `sudo yarn global remove <package_name>` works and I tried to remove **expo-cli**. Replace <package_name> with package you want to remove.