# ESLint - Error: Must use import to load ES Module

Tags: javascript, node.js, reactjs, eslint

I am currently setting up a boilerplate with React, TypeScript, styled components, [Webpack](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Webpack), etc., and I am getting an error when trying to run [ESLint](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ESLint):

> Error: Must use import to load ES Module

Here is a more verbose version of the error:

```
/Users/ben/Desktop/development projects/react-boilerplate-styled-context/src/api/api.ts
  0:0  error  Parsing error: Must use import to load ES Module: /Users/ben/Desktop/development projects/react-boilerplate-styled-context/node_modules/eslint/node_modules/eslint-scope/lib/definition.js
require() of ES modules is not supported.
require() of /Users/ben/Desktop/development projects/react-boilerplate-styled-context/node_modules/eslint/node_modules/eslint-scope/lib/definition.js from /Users/ben/Desktop/development projects/react-boilerplate-styled-context/node_modules/babel-eslint/lib/require-from-eslint.js is an ES module file as it is a .js file whose nearest parent package.json contains "type": "module" which defines all .js files in that package scope as ES modules.
Instead rename definition.js to end in .cjs, change the requiring code to use import(), or remove "type": "module" from /Users/ben/Desktop/development projects/react-boilerplate-styled-context/node_modules/eslint/node_modules/eslint-scope/package.json
```

The error occurs in every single one of my .js and .ts/ .tsx files where I only use `import` or the file doesn't even have an import at all. I understand what the error is saying, but I don't have any idea why it is being thrown when in fact I only use imports or even no imports at all in some files.

Here is my *package.json* file where I trigger the linter from using `npm run lint:eslint:quiet`:

```
{
  "name": "my-react-boilerplate",
  "version": "1.0.0",
  "description": "",
  "main": "index.tsx",
  "directories": {
    "test": "test"
  },
  "engines": {
    "node": ">=14.0.0"
  },
  "type": "module",
  "scripts": {
    "build": "webpack --config webpack.prod.js",
    "dev": "webpack serve --config webpack.dev.js",
    "lint": "npm run typecheck && npm run lint:css && npm run lint:eslint:quiet",
    "lint:css": "stylelint './src/**/*.{js,ts,tsx}'",
    "lint:eslint:quiet": "eslint --ext .ts,.tsx,.js,.jsx  ./src --no-error-on-unmatched-pattern --quiet",
    "lint:eslint": "eslint --ext .ts,.tsx,.js,.jsx  ./src --no-error-on-unmatched-pattern",
    "lint:eslint:fix": "eslint --ext .ts,.tsx,.js,.jsx  ./src --no-error-on-unmatched-pattern --quiet --fix",
    "test": "cross-env NODE_ENV=test jest --coverage",
    "test:watch": "cross-env NODE_ENV=test jest --watchAll",
    "typecheck": "tsc --noEmit",
    "precommit": "npm run lint"
  },
  "lint-staged": {
    "*.{ts,tsx,js,jsx}": [
      "npm run lint:eslint:fix",
      "git add --force"
    ],
    "*.{md,json}": [
      "prettier --write",
      "git add --force"
    ]
  },
  "husky": {
    "hooks": {
      "pre-commit": "npx lint-staged && npm run typecheck"
    }
  },
  "resolutions": {
    "styled-components": "^5"
  },
  "author": "",
  "license": "ISC",
  "devDependencies": {
    "@babel/core": "^7.5.4",
    "@babel/plugin-proposal-class-properties": "^7.5.0",
    "@babel/preset-env": "^7.5.4",
    "@babel/preset-react": "^7.0.0",
    "@types/history": "^4.7.6",
    "@types/react": "^17.0.29",
    "@types/react-dom": "^17.0.9",
    "@types/react-router": "^5.1.17",
    "@types/react-router-dom": "^5.1.5",
    "@types/styled-components": "^5.1.15",
    "@typescript-eslint/eslint-plugin": "^5.0.0",
    "babel-cli": "^6.26.0",
    "babel-eslint": "^10.0.2",
    "babel-loader": "^8.0.0-beta.6",
    "babel-polyfill": "^6.26.0",
    "babel-preset-env": "^1.7.0",
    "babel-preset-react": "^6.24.1",
    "babel-preset-stage-2": "^6.24.1",
    "clean-webpack-plugin": "^4.0.0",
    "dotenv-webpack": "^7.0.3",
    "error-overlay-webpack-plugin": "^1.0.0",
    "eslint": "^8.0.0",
    "eslint-config-airbnb": "^18.2.0",
    "eslint-config-prettier": "^8.3.0",
    "eslint-config-with-prettier": "^6.0.0",
    "eslint-plugin-compat": "^3.3.0",
    "eslint-plugin-import": "^2.25.2",
    "eslint-plugin-jsx-a11y": "^6.2.3",
    "eslint-plugin-prettier": "^4.0.0",
    "eslint-plugin-react": "^7.14.2",
    "eslint-plugin-react-hooks": "^4.2.0",
    "extract-text-webpack-plugin": "^3.0.2",
    "file-loader": "^6.2.0",
    "html-webpack-plugin": "^5.3.2",
    "husky": "^7.0.2",
    "prettier": "^2.4.1",
    "raw-loader": "^4.0.2",
    "style-loader": "^3.3.0",
    "stylelint": "^13.13.1",
    "stylelint-config-recommended": "^5.0.0",
    "stylelint-config-styled-components": "^0.1.1",
    "stylelint-processor-styled-components": "^1.10.0",
    "ts-loader": "^9.2.6",
    "tslint": "^6.1.3",
    "typescript": "^4.4.4",
    "url-loader": "^4.1.1",
    "webpack": "^5.58.2",
    "webpack-cli": "^4.2.0",
    "webpack-dev-server": "^4.3.1",
    "webpack-merge": "^5.3.0"
  },
  "dependencies": {
    "history": "^4.10.0",
    "process": "^0.11.10",
    "react": "^17.0.1",
    "react-dom": "^17.0.1",
    "react-router-dom": "^5.2.0",
    "styled-components": "^5.2.1"
  }
}
```

Here is my .eslintrc file:

```
{
  "extends": ["airbnb", "prettier"],
  "parser": "babel-eslint",
  "plugins": ["prettier", "@typescript-eslint"],
  "parserOptions": {
    "ecmaVersion": 8,
    "ecmaFeatures": {
      "experimentalObjectRestSpread": true,
      "impliedStrict": true,
      "classes": true
    }
  },
  "env": {
    "browser": true,
    "node": true,
    "jest": true
  },
  "rules": {
    "arrow-body-style": ["error", "as-needed"],
    "class-methods-use-this": 0,
    "react/jsx-filename-extension": 0,
    "global-require": 0,
    "react/destructuring-assignment": 0,
    "import/named": 2,
    "linebreak-style": 0,
    "import/no-dynamic-require": 0,
    "import/no-named-as-default": 0,
    "import/no-unresolved": 2,
    "import/prefer-default-export": 0,
    "semi": [2, "always"],
    "max-len": [
      "error",
      {
        "code": 80,
        "ignoreUrls": true,
        "ignoreComments": true,
        "ignoreStrings": true,
        "ignoreTemplateLiterals": true
      }
    ],
    "new-cap": [
      2,
      {
        "capIsNew": false,
        "newIsCap": true
      }
    ],
    "no-param-reassign": 0,
    "no-shadow": 0,
    "no-tabs": 2,
    "no-underscore-dangle": 0,
    "react/forbid-prop-types": [
      "error",
      {
        "forbid": ["any"]
      }
    ],
    "import/no-extraneous-dependencies": ["error", { "devDependencies": true }],
    "react/jsx-no-bind": [
      "error",
      {
        "ignoreRefs": true,
        "allowArrowFunctions": true,
        "allowBind": false
      }
    ],
    "react/no-unknown-property": [
      2,
      {
        "ignore": ["itemscope", "itemtype", "itemprop"]
      }
    ]
  }
}
```

And I’m not sure if it is relevant, but here is also my *tsconfig.eslint.json* file:

```
{
  "extends": "./tsconfig.json",
  "include": ["./src/**/*.ts", "./src/**/*.tsx", "./src/**/*.js"],
  "exclude": ["node_modules/**", "build/**", "coverage/**"]
}
```

How can I fix this?

Googling the error does not present any useful forums or raised bugs. Most of them just state not to use `require` in your files which I am not.

Comment: *(Had the same problem described in the title, though the specifics were different. Solved my problem using Mariusz's solution, below. It is easier than the accepted answer, so you might want to try it first.)*

Answer (score 420, accepted):

I think the problem is that you are trying to use the deprecated [babel-eslint parser](https://github.com/babel/babel-eslint), last updated a year ago, which looks like it doesn't support ES6 modules.  Updating to the [latest parser](https://github.com/babel/babel/tree/main/eslint/babel-eslint-parser) seems to work, at least for simple linting.

So, do this:

- In package.json, update the line `"babel-eslint": "^10.0.2",` to `"@babel/eslint-parser": "^7.5.4",`.  This works with the code above but it may be better to use the latest version, which at the time of writing is 7.19.1.
- Run `npm i` from a terminal/command prompt in the folder
- In .eslintrc, update the parser line `"parser": "babel-eslint",` to `"parser": "@babel/eslint-parser",`
- In .eslintrc, add `"requireConfigFile": false,` to the parserOptions section (underneath `"ecmaVersion": 8,`) (I needed this or babel was looking for config files I don't have)
- Run the command to lint a file

Then, for me with just your two configuration files, the error goes away and I get appropriate linting errors.

Comment: I have the same problem, where can I find the .eslintrc file?

Comment: It's normally in the same folder as package.json. However, it may be elsewhere. From the command line it can be specified, or eslint will look in the folder of the file your are linting or any parent folder. If you're using a framework or an IDE plugin it may be elsewhere too! It also doesn't have to be called .eslintrc: [there are several options for other names and formats](https://eslint.org/docs/user-guide/configuring/configuration-files#configuration-file-formats), including putting the config in package.json itself.  In short, it would help everyone if this were a bit simpler.

Comment: Unfortunately, this does not work for me. Does anyone was successful using this solution?

Comment: Yes @DavidH - It worked for me. Try restarting the code editor to reflect the changes, or try deleting `node_modules` folder and do a fresh npm install. It should work.

Comment: Can't find `requireConfigFile` in [parserOptions docs](https://eslint.org/docs/user-guide/configuring/language-options#specifying-parser-options)

Comment: @vsync It's a parser configuration option specific to the @babel/eslint-parser.  There is some [documentation on the parser Github site](https://github.com/babel/babel/tree/main/eslint/babel-eslint-parser#additional-parser-configuration).

Comment: /* import/no-import-module-exports */

Use the given line, in top of the page and error will go away fro this

Answer (score 8):

The problem can be easily resolved by changing the file extension of .eslintrc from js to json (exporting the .eslintrc object using ESM format in .eslintrc.js just doesn't work).

Answer (score 4):

If you did all above and still fails, reload your vscode.

Answer (score 3):

#### (possible) solution

change `.eslintrc.js` to `.eslintrc.cjs`

- *(this worked in my case, not sure why)*

#### situation

```
Cannot read config file: H:\Using\code_comment_remover-ui-awstest\.eslintrc.js
Error: require() of ES Module H:\Using\code_comment_remover-ui-awstest\.eslintrc.js from H:\Using\code_comment_remover-ui-awstest\node_modules\.pnpm\@eslint+eslintrc@1.4.1\node_modules\@eslint\eslintrc\dist\eslintrc.cjs not supported.
Instead change the require of .eslintrc.js in H:\Using\code_comment_remover-ui-awstest\node_modules\.pnpm\@eslint+eslintrc@1.4.1\node_modules\@eslint\eslintrc\dist\eslintrc.cjs to a dynamic import() which is available in all CommonJS modules.
```

#### related

> [] 
> I think we could update the `--init` command to read `package.json`, and if it has `"type": "module"` then create `.eslintrc.cjs` instead of `.eslintrc.js`. 
> <> 
> https://github.com/eslint/eslint/issues/14137

Answer (score 1):

This can happen with quite a lot of lately released frameworks like [Vue.js](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Vue.js) or [Nuxt.js](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Nuxt.js), mostly because of the usage of [ESM](https://hacks.mozilla.org/2018/03/es-modules-a-cartoon-deep-dive/) modules (not fully or at all supported by older [Node.js](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Node.js) versions).

The fastest approach for this is to use something like [nvm](https://github.com/nvm-sh/nvm), after installing it, you could run:

- `nvm i 16` (v16 is the latest LTS as of time of writing)
- `nvm use 16`

And you'll be running the project with a full ESM support.
You can double check that by running `node -v`.

Comment: On Windows I used `nvm-setup.exe` https://github.com/coreybutler/nvm-windows/releases and had to run `nvm install 16` rather than `nvm i 16` which didn't seem to work.

Answer (score 1):

I followed @rich-n advice from a comment above, and according to [this](https://github.com/babel/babel/tree/main/eslint/babel-eslint-parser#additional-parser-configuration):

go to `.eslintrc.js` and make sure you have the following settings:

```
module.exports = {
  parser: "@babel/eslint-parser",
  parserOptions: {
    requireConfigFile: false,
    babelOptions: {
      babelrc: false,
      configFile: false,
      // your babel options
      presets: ["@babel/preset-env"],
    },
  },
};
```

doing this removed all the "red" marks from vscode :)

Answer (score 1):

I just delete `node_modules`, and re installed through `npm install`, and now it works.

Answer (score 0):

In [Visual Studio Code](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Visual_Studio_Code), remove the ESLint extension, and install it again.

Comment: Doesn't works for me

Comment: Worked for me. I was getting the error after changing some dependency versions.

Comment: doesn;t work for me either

Answer (score 0):

#### For a React Native setup using the *eslint-config-react-native-community package*

I did what the [accepted answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/69557309/8040054) suggested to do, but I didn't have any `"babel-eslint": "^10.0.2",` line in my *package.json* file of the root folder.

- Go to `node_modules/@react-native-community/eslint-config`
- Edit package.json, change `"babel-eslint": "^10.0.2",` to `"@babel/eslint-parser": "^7.18.2",`
- Edit file *index.js*, change `"parser": "babel-eslint",` to `parser: '@babel/eslint-parser',`
- Go to the root folder of your project and `npm i -D @babel/eslint-parser`
- Run the lint command

It worked for me this way.

Answer (score 0):

"test": "react-scripts test --transformIgnorePatterns "node_modules/(?!axios)/""

use this worked for me.

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Answer (score 0):

For anyone who doesn't want to install babel parser:
Eslint uses [espree](https://github.com/eslint/espree) parser by default. So you can simply tell eslint config to expect modules:

```
  "parserOptions": {
    "ecmaVersion": "latest",
    "sourceType": "module"
  },
```

Answer (score -1):

Not sure if I'm missing something for this solution to not be here, but the error output advises renaming your eslint config file from `<name>.js` to `<name>.cjs`. This was all I had to do.

So basically RTFE.

Answer (score -4):

"@babel/eslint-parser" depends on "@babel/core". So after "npm install @babel/eslint-parser -S", you should use `npm i @babel/core -S`.