# What is causing Error: .eslintrc.js: Environment key "vue/setup-compiler-macros" is unknown

Tags: vue.js, eslint, eslintrc

I am developing a sample app using Vue 3 and Typescript.
Specifically, I am using the new Vue v3.2 setup option in the  section of the Vue SFC. Vue docs advise me to add
"vue/setup-compiler-macros"  to the env secyion of the eslintrc.js file which was working. But I am now getting an error

```
Syntax Error: Error: .eslintrc.js:
        Environment key "vue/setup-compiler-macros" is unknown
    at Array.forEach (<anonymous>)
```

for a while this seemed to disappear if I restarted VS Code (not a great workaround, I admit), but now even this does not work. The error occurs when I save a file and the project is compiled.
I appear to be using VS Code extension - ESLint v2.2.2.

eslintrc.js:

```
  module.exports = {
  root: true,
  env: {
    'vue/setup-compiler-macros': true,
    node: true,
  },
  extends: [
    'plugin:vue/vue3-essential',
    'eslint:recommended',
    '@vue/typescript/recommended',
  ],
  parserOptions: {
    ecmaVersion: 2020,
  },
  rules: {
    'no-console': process.env.NODE_ENV === 'production' ? 'warn' : 'off',
    'no-debugger': process.env.NODE_ENV === 'production' ? 'warn' : 'off',
  },
}
```

Any ideas would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: Additional info: 

```"devDependencies": {
    "@typescript-eslint/eslint-plugin": "^4.18.0",
    "@typescript-eslint/parser": "^4.18.0",
    "@vue/cli-plugin-babel": "~4.5.0",
    "@vue/cli-plugin-eslint": "^4.5.15",
    "@vue/cli-plugin-router": "~4.5.0",
    "@vue/cli-plugin-typescript": "~4.5.0",
    "@vue/cli-service": "~4.5.0",
    "@vue/compiler-sfc": "^3.0.0",
    "@vue/eslint-config-typescript": "^7.0.0",
    "apollo": "^2.33.7",
    "eslint": "^6.7.2",
    "eslint-plugin-vue": "^7.0.0",
    "typescript": "~4.1.5"
  }```

Answer (score 11, accepted):

I had the same problem, solved by config

```
  globals: {
    defineProps: "readonly",
    defineEmits: "readonly"
  }
```

the [offical guide](https://eslint.vuejs.org/user-guide/#faq) is here, I dont't know the `'vue/setup-compiler-macros': true,` why not work

Comment: Thanks - that works. And I have raised a bug report for eslinter as well.

Comment: `'vue/setup-compiler-macros': true` is work, you need to add this line to env, not to rules.

Comment: Per another answer, you need `eslint-plugin-vue` `^8.0.0` for that `env` flag to work. Also for this answer's solution, you may also want to add `withDefaults` and any other of the macros you're using.

Answer (score 13):

You need to upgrade `eslint-plugin-vue` to version 8 which added it according to its release notes.
Se also https://github.com/vuejs/eslint-plugin-vue/pull/1685

Comment: Doing this and adding the "vue/setup-compiler-macros": true flag worked for me.

Answer (score 2):

You can check [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/69557309/1374576) which helped me properly solve this problem.

You basically need to:

1. Remove `babel-eslint` by running `npm uni -D babel-eslint` on your terminal.
2. Install `@babel/eslint-parser` by running `npm i -D @babel/eslint-parser` on your terminal.
3. Update the `env` line in your ESLint config (could be inside `.eslintrc.js`, `.eslintrc.json` or `package.json`) with the following:

```js
  env: {
    node: true,
    'vue/setup-compiler-macros': true,
  },
```

4. Update the `parserOptions` line in your ESLint config with the following:

```js
  parserOptions: {
    parser: '@babel/eslint-parser',
    ecmaVersion: 2018,
    requireConfigFile: false, // This will prevent Babel from looking for a config file you possibly don’t have or need.
  },
```

5. If there’s a `parser` line outside `parserOptions`, you can simply remove it to avoid conflicts.

Answer (score 1):

Creating an eslintrc.is file with the configurations didn't work for me.

I fixed this error without running any upgrades, all I did was add the "vue/setup-compiler-macros: true" in the eslintConfig part of the package.json file

That is:

```
"eslintConfig": {
    ...
    "env": {
        node: true,
        "vue/setup-compiler-macros": true
    }
}
```