# Nuxt/ESLint - Parsing error: Must use import to load ES Module

Tags: javascript, node.js, module

I am using Nuxt 2.15.7 in VS Code, using Node version 14.17.1 and the eslint extension.

**The problem**

I started seeing a red squiggly line under the 1st character of every file. When hovering over it, this is the error I see:

```
require() of ES modules is not supported.
require() of C:\Users\SR Gears\Documents\work\my-website\node_modules\eslint\node_modules\eslint-scope\lib\definition.js 
from C:\Users\SR Gears\Documents\work\my-website\node_modules\babel-eslint\lib\require-from-eslint.js 
is an ES module file as it is a .js file whose nearest parent package.json contains "type": "module" which defines all .js files in that package scope as ES modules.

Instead rename definition.js to end in .cjs, 
change the requiring code to use import(), 
or remove "type": "module" from 
C:\Users\SR Gears\Documents\work\my-website\node_modules\eslint\node_modules\eslint-scope\package.json.eslint
```

**What I have tried so far**

First, I tried renaming the appropriate files as listed above in the error, and restarting the eslint server, but the error remains.

So, I went over to the eslint extension in VS Code and read the following:

```
The approval flow to allow the execution of a ESLint library got reworked. Its initial experience is now as follows:

- no modal dialog is shown when the ESLint extension tries to load an ESLint library for the first time and an approval is necessary. Instead the ESLint status bar item changes to ESLint status icon indicating that the execution is currently block.
- if the active text editor content would be validated using ESLint, a problem at the top of the file is shown in addition.

The execution of the ESLint library can be denied or approved using the following gestures:

- clicking on the status bar icon
- using the quick fix for the corresponding ESLint problem
- executing the command ESLint: Manage Library Execution from the command palette
```

Okay, so I tried the above suggestions:

- clicking on the status bar icon (*it isn't there in my status bar*)
- using the quick fix for the corresponding ESLint problem (*shows no quick fix available*)
- executing the command ESLint: Manage Library Execution from the command palette (*I get a message that this request is unknown*)

**Potential Fix with error**

So, I navigated over to `eslintrc.js` I hovered over `module.exports = {` on line 1, and got the lightbulb icon show. The Quick Fix says **Convert to ES6 module**. When I click this, the file is updated. All variable keys within the options are updated to have `export` in front of them. This *does* remove the error line at the top of the files, but gives a new error for `export const extends: []` variable:
`'extends' is not allowed as a variable declaration name.`. My eslintrc.js file (before updating to ES6 module) is here:

**eslintrc.js**

```
module.exports = {
  root: true,
  env: {
    browser: true,
    node: true
  },
  parserOptions: {
    parser: 'babel-eslint'
  },
  extends: [
    'plugin:nuxt/recommended',
    'plugin:vue/recommended',
    'eslint:recommended',
    // 'prettier/vue',
    'plugin:prettier/recommended'
  ],
  globals: {
    $nuxt: true,
    page: true,
    browser: true,
    context: true,
    jestPuppeteer: true
  },
  plugins: ['nuxt', 'vue', 'prettier'],
  rules: {
    'new-cap': 'off',
    'no-console': process.env.NODE_ENV === 'production' ? 'error' : 'off',
    'no-debugger': process.env.NODE_ENV === 'production' ? 'error' : 'off',
    'vue/component-name-in-template-casing': ['off', 'PascalCase'],
    'vue/attribute-hyphenation': ['warn'],
    'vue/no-unused-components': ['warn'],
    'vue/html-self-closing': [
      'error',
      {
        html: {
          void: 'any',
          normal: 'always',
          component: 'always'
        },
        svg: 'always',
        math: 'always'
      }
    ],
    'vue/max-attributes-per-line': 'off',
    'vue/no-v-html': 'off',
    'no-unused-vars': ['warn'],
    eqeqeq: ['warn'],
    'no-lonely-if': ['warn'],
    'require-await': ['warn'],
    'handle-callback-err': ['warn'],
    'space-before-function-paren': 0
  }
}
```

**One other potential fix - but not for me**

For anyone else with the same errors, there is a fix here, (that also worked for me): [ESlint - Error: Must use import to load ES Module](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/69554485/eslint-error-must-use-import-to-load-es-module) `

I cannot use this fix though, as my team suggested that adjusting babel settings can create errors elsewhere.

As that cannot be my solution, would anyone else know how to manage this error? Here is my nuxt.config file. If you need to see something else, I can update it here too.

**nuxt.config**

```
import { storyblokConfig, localeMessages } from './config'

export default {
  // Target: https://go.nuxtjs.dev/config-target
  target: 'server',
  ssr: true,
  dev: false,

  // Global page headers: https://go.nuxtjs.dev/config-head
  head: {
    title: '',
    htmlAttrs: {
      lang: 'en'
    },
    meta: [
      { charset: 'utf-8' },
      { name: 'viewport', content: 'width=device-width, initial-scale=1' },
      { hid: 'description', name: 'description', content: '' }
    ],
    link: [
      {
        rel: 'icon',
        sizes: '192x192',
        href: '/favicon/android-chrome-192x192.png'
      },
      {
        rel: 'icon',
        sizes: '512x512',
        href: '/favicon/android-chrome-512x512.png'
      },
      {
        rel: 'apple-touch-icon',
        sizes: '180x180',
        href: '/favicon/apple-touch-icon.png'
      },
      { rel: 'icon', sizes: '16x16', href: '/favicon/favicon-16x16.png' },
      { rel: 'icon', sizes: '32x32', href: '/favicon/favicon-32x32.png' },
      { rel: 'icon', type: 'image/x-icon', href: '/favicon/favicon.ico' },
      { rel: 'manifest', href: '/favicon/site.webmanifest' }
    ]
  },

  // Global CSS: https://go.nuxtjs.dev/config-css
  css: [
    '~assets/styles/main.css',
    '~assets/fonts/fabrikat/stylesheet.css',
    '~assets/fonts/pangram/stylesheet.css'
  ],

  // Plugins to run before rendering page: https://go.nuxtjs.dev/config-plugins
  plugins: [
    { src: '~/plugins/logger.js' },
    { src: '~/plugins/nujek-ui.js' },
    { src: '~/plugins/validation.js' },
    { src: '~/plugins/utils.js' },
    { src: '~/plugins/vue-tailwind.js' },
    { src: '~/plugins/rich-text-renderer.js' },
    { src: '~/plugins/defaultButton.js' }
  ],

  // Auto import components: https://go.nuxtjs.dev/config-components
  components: [{ path: '~/components', pathPrefix: false, prefix: '' }],

  // Modules for dev and build (recommended): https://go.nuxtjs.dev/config-modules
  buildModules: [
    // https://go.nuxtjs.dev/eslint
    '@nuxtjs/eslint-module',
    // https://go.nuxtjs.dev/tailwindcss
    '@nuxtjs/tailwindcss',
    '@nuxtjs/composition-api/module',
    '@nuxtjs/tailwindcss',
    [
      '@nujek/ui',
      {
        withConsole: true,
        storeTemplates: {
          nav: true
        }
      }
    ],
    ['@nujek/storyblok']
  ],

  nujekStoryblok: {
    storyblokConfig,
    withConsole: false,
    debug: true
  },

  // Modules: https://go.nuxtjs.dev/config-modules
  modules: ['nuxt-i18n', '~/modules/nuxt-storyblok-queries/lib/module.js'],

  storyblokQueries: storyblokConfig,

  i18n: {
    locales: [
      {
        code: 'en',
        iso: 'en-US'
      },
      {
        code: 'de',
        iso: 'de-DE'
      }
    ],
    defaultLocale: 'de',
    strategy: 'prefix_except_default',
    detectBrowserLanguage: {
      useCookie: true,
      cookieKey: 'i18n_redirected',
      redirectOn: 'root'
    },
    vueI18n: {
      fallbackLocale: 'de',
      silentTranslationWarn: true,
      messages: localeMessages
    },
    vuex: {
      syncLocale: true,
      syncMessages: true
    }
  },

  // publicRuntimeConfig: {
  //   accessToken: process.env.SB_CLIENT_ACCESS_TOKEN
  // },

  // Build Configuration: https://go.nuxtjs.dev/config-build
  build: {
    transpile: ['vee-validate', '@marvr/storyblok-rich-text-vue-renderer']
  }
}
```

**c:/users/user/AppData/Roaming/Code/User/settings.json**

```
{
    "workbench.colorTheme": "Default Dark+",
    "terminal.integrated.defaultProfile.windows": "Git Bash",
    "editor.wordWrap": "on",
    "editor.codeActionsOnSave": {
        "source.fixAll.eslint": true
    },
    "eslint.validate": ["javascript"]
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I met this error today on a fresh installation of nuxt.

It would `npm run dev` fine on the first time, but whenever I changed a file, the hot reloading would give an eslint error, as if trying to lint my eslint files.

I solved it by updating Nodejs and npm to their latest version and creating a new nuxt app.

It's probably not the answer you've been looking for, but maybe it will help others.